# Filter and calculate based on average

Tags: sql

My question is: List all staff whose salary is greater than the average salary, and show how much is the difference.

```
SELECT staffname 
FROM   staff 
WHERE  salary >= (SELECT Avg(salary) 
                  FROM   staff) 
        AND (SELECT Max(salary) AS Max_Salary, 
                   Avg(salary) AS Avg_Salary 
            FROM   staff 
            WHERE  salary = max_salary - avg_salary)
```

The salary which is greater than the average salary is coming out just fine, but I can't show how much is the different.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT staffname, staff.salary - avg.salary
FROM staff, (SELECT AVG(salary) salary FROM staff) avg
WHERE staff.salary > avg.salary
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Count(*), (Select Avg(Salary) From Staff)
From Staff
Where Salary > (Select Avg(Salary) From Staff);
```